# C# - asynchronous sockets with timeout

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am implementing a piece of software that reads a list of ids from a message queue. Once some come through, I would like to pass each one through a socket to a third party application, that will then process it and return a value back once it's done.

If the third party app takes too long to reply, I want to report this and maybe even close the connection.

Furthermore, this should run asynchronously, that is, once the messages are read from the queue, a separate task is started to handle it being sent to the socket and any subsequent communication.

Following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx) I have created a class that spawns a task and sends an exception after a timeout threshold.

```
 public async Task Run(Action action, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(action).TimeoutAfter(timeoutInSeconds);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException te)
        {
           //add error capture here or retry 
        }
    }

 public static async Task TimeoutAfter(this Task task, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeoutInSeconds*1000)))
        {
            await task;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new TimeoutException(string.Format("Task {0} timed out after {1} seconds", task.Id, timeoutInSeconds));
        }
    }
```

Next I created another class to asynchronously listen to connections.

```
public class SocketListener
{
...
    public async void Listen(Action action)
    {
        //initialization code
        var listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, Port);
        listener.Start(numberOfConnections);

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //wait for client to connect
                var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                //do something once client is connected
                var task = new TaskWithTimeout();
                await task.Run(() => action, 10);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log error
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Here, after the client connects successfully, I want to call a method that will handle communication between server and client. If the client takes too long to respond, the TaskWithTimeout should throw an exception and move on.

My thought process was to call SocketListener once I read from the queue

```
public void ProcessQueue() {
    //initialize SocketListener
    listener.Listen(MethodToHandleCommunication)
    ...
}
```

Now I am a bit stuck. Preferably, SocketListener should be able to handle any type of communication, and that's why I thought I'd pass the Action as a parameter, so that I can determine what method I want to run from outside (by this I mean that if in the future I need to pass different data to the client, I would be able to reuse this code). However with this approach, I cannot even pass the client object back to the action.

In general I feel like I'm taking the wrong approach, and I am sure there's a better and more efficient way of doing what I want. As you can see I'm fairly new to parallel programming in general. I am a bit frustrated with this and would greatly appreciate any help or insight from SO

Comment: `However with this approach, I cannot even pass the client object back to the action.` So, why not use `Action<TcpClient>`?

Comment: If I do that, then I wouldn't be able to use the TaskWithTimeout class. I don't think there's a way to implement that class to accept any type of Action or Func with any parameters, is there?

Comment: You would pass a lambda to the `TaskWithTimeout` class, like this: `await task.Run(() => action(client), 10);`

Comment: Thanks Stephen! That works as I want it to.